# Change str to float including + and - values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using mssql 2012 version

Example value

```
     col
0  '-1.1+1'
1  '-1.0-1'
2  '1.1+2'
3  '1.1-2'
```

I want this Result

```
     col
0    -1.1
1    -1.0
2    1.1
3    1.1
```

if table name is 'tb' and column name is 'col' how can get the result?

I'm tried Try_convert() but can't reach the answer

Comment: basically you want to ignore anything from the last `+` or `-` sign ?

Comment: yes I want to delete last + and - sign after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reverse the string and then use `patindex` to find the `+` or `-` symbol. Then use `left()` to extract the required portion

```
left(col, len(col) - patindex('%[+-]%', reverse(col)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUBSTRING with reverse function.

```sql
select reverse(substring(reverse(col),3,len(col))) as modified_col 
from (values ('1.0+1'),('-1.1-1')) as t(col)
```

[DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=abec40e6464426f9c319e682062f3090)